# Android Preferences: How to validate their values ? specially EdiBoxPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How do we validate values input into the EditBoxPrefence ?

For example user enters a directory name like

myfolder//  or /myfolder or

I want to trim any slashes and then store the value for the preference
How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could test the value and tell the user something is wrong:
or do whatever you want

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    Your_Pref = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("Your_Pref");

    Your_Pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Boolean rtnval = true;
            if (Your_Test) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Invalid Input");
                builder.setMessage("Something's gone wrong...");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.show();
                rtnval = false;
            }
            return rtnval;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, how about processing the value and saving the processed value without prompting ?